# Open DB connection only once for all requests

Tags: node.js, express

In my below code, I am trying to open DB connection before "/post" request. I can solve the below issue using global connection but is there any other way to do it by just binding db connection to the current request.

```
//Model.js
function DB(){
    this.DBConn (req, res, next) {
        var conn = <db connection string>;
        pg.connect(conn, function (err, client) {
        req.db = client;
        })
    this.create (req, res, next) {
        // Using req.db.query(), to execute INSERT query
        }
    }
}
//server.js
var DB = require('./model.js');
var app = express.Router();
// Open DB connection
new DB.DBConn(); //How to pass request in this function
app.post('/post', DB.create);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using Express 4 just a suggestion I'd use the Router object instead of app. But regardless, if you make a module for your db it will hold the instance inside of it, just pull down a sample from my github repo [here](https://github.com/lunchboxsuhi/mongodb-nativedrive-node).

If you take a look through it you'll notice that if you make the database a module, then have an initialize function which is called when your app is being created it gives it the abstraction it needs to follow the micro service architecture schema along with providing you with the single connection call so you don't constantly close/open.

below is the database.js file

```js
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

var uri = 'some database connection string for mongodb ';

function initilizeDb(cb) {
  mongodb.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err);
      return;
    }

    exports.db = db; //this is the part you need to do in sql connection or w.e after you get the async connection handler.
    cb(null);
  });
};

exports.initDb = initilizeDb;
```

as you can see we export the initialDb function and the exports.db inside of the initialized function. all modules share an instance with the same module which is why the db reference is valid.

there is no reason to keep passing around the instance it just brings layers to keep an eye on when you are refactoring or looking for bugs. Abstracts as much you can - within reason.